# Decomposing representations of general linear group.

Tags: representation-theory, general-linear-group

I understand that given an integer partition we can define an irreducible representation of the general linear group by a Schur functor. Given an irreducible representation $W$ of $GL\left(V\right)$ constructed from the partition $\lambda$ I would like to know how to decompose $S^2W$ into irreducible components. e.g. if $W=V$ then $S^2W$ is already irreducible. How do I work out the decomposition in general?

Comment: I tried to create the "plethysm" tag before, but that got rejected. Maybe that would be appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general understanding the composition of two Schur functors (called plethysm) is quite a difficult and subtle question.  However in the special case of the symmetric and exterior squares we do have a nice combinatorial interpretation in terms of so called domino tableaux due to Carre and Leclerc. The relevant reference is here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022475927626